# Javascript/jQuery/CSS. How do I maintain drag events outside the target div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am implementing a scrollbar using jQuery/Javascript/CSS. The usual. Everything is going according to plan except for the following use case:

The user mouses down in the scrollbar div hosting mousedown/mousemove/mouseup event handlers. The user initiates a drag gesture - mousemove starts firing - that soon moves the cursor **outside** the bounds of the scrollbar div and onto the surrounding div real estate on the web page. The moment this happens, mousemove - as expected - stops firing events.

How do I continue to have mousemove fire events without resorting to just attaching a mousemove  handler to the root div? How do I maintain scrollbar dragger translation even though the cursor has wandered off the scrollbar?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Instead of using onmousemove on the element, use it on the document.

Comment: Mandera. Bingo! Say this as an answer my friend.

Comment: Shameless answer added ^^ Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onmousemove on the element, use it on the document.